# Comparing SQL Server execution plans, why does code with more than double the "cost" run in half the time?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-execution-plan

While I understand joins to be more efficient, I was surprised when this join

```
SELECT      COUNT(1)
FROM        dbo.Table1 t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN   dbo.Table2 t2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON t1.PrimaryKey = t2.ForeignKey
WHERE       t2.ForeignKey IS NULL
```

had a cost of more than double this

```
SELECT  COUNT(1)
FROM    dbo.Table1 p WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE   PrimaryKey NOT IN (SELECT ForeignKey FROM dbo.Table2 WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ForeignKey IS NOT NULL)
```

and yet, as expected, the first ran much faster (it took about half as much time).  Both tables are relatively large (about 10 million rows).  My main concern is that, when I can't run sample code, I use cost to determine what should perform the best.  Yet the cost (both from estimated and actual execution plans) would have led me wrong here.  What am I missing?

Comment: While it has nothing to do with execution plan costs, please do [kick the bad habit of reflexively putting `NOLOCK` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). It basically means "I don't care if I get back incorrect results", which is only rarely true.

Comment: As for the "costs" the optimizer determines, I've personally learned to ignore these in lieu of focusing on row counts and time (`set statistics io on`/`set statistics time on`). Especially for estimated execution plans the cost tends to be almost meaningless and can be very far off the mark, while for actual execution plans it's still no more than a rough indication based on both CPU and I/O (when you are better off looking at these separately) and doesn't take things like parallelism bottlenecks into account. There is no alternative to actually running a query for getting actual performance.

Comment: Query cost doesn't necessarily correlate with runtime. You may have a cheaper query which is forced to run serially, hence it'll come back in more time.

Comment: For SQL performance help, you need to supply us with the full query, table *and index* definitions, and share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Most likely there is bad or not-existent indexing on `Table2`, which is causing a [poor row-goal estimate](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/03/sql-performance/row-goals-part-4-anti-join-anti-pattern). But without basic info we cannot help.